# Visual Basic Функция

Tags: visual-basic

```
 Dim a!, b!, c!
 Private Sub Form_Load()
 a = Round((3 * Log(2) / Log(10)), 3)
 b = Round(Cos(pi / 3), 3)
 c = Round(7 ^ (1 / 3), 3)
 Text1.Text = a: Text2.Text = b: Text3.Text = c
 End Sub
 Private Sub Command1_Click()
 Rem 
 x = Val(Text4.Text)
If x > a Then
 f = Round((Atn(b + x)) + Cos(b), 3)
Text5.Text = x: Text7.Text = f
ElseIf x = a Then
f = Round(Atn(x - b) - (1.3 * x), 3)
Text6.Text = x: Text8.Text = f
 Else
 z = (1.5 + x)
 f = Round(Atn(z / (1.3 * a) + (c ^ 3 * b)), 3)
 Text9.Text = x: Text10.Text = f
 End If
 End Sub
```

[image: Задание]

Не получаются ответы которые нужны, видно в задании, хелп что делаю не так??

Comment: последняя формула неправильная

Comment: да с последней что-то намутил , но и две предыдущие не правильно считают, либо  ответ не правильный либо я не правильно сделал

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Сам натупил ,должно совпадать только одно число с X